# Having been run as an .exe, the django admin panel hides models except users and user groups

Tags: django, django-admin, pyinstaller

I created the most simple Python/Django project following to the standard procedure: virtual environment => startproject, startapp, simple model with one Char field. Also I add my model to the admin.py file. Then I ran makemigrations, migrate, createsuperuser.

If I run like 
`python manage.py runserver`
then everything is perfect: I can view and edit my model.

But I need to run my program as a single exe-file. For that purpose I use PyInstaller with default settings. The exe file is generated with no errors.

And here is the problem: there is no my model at the Admin Panel except User and User Groups.

My environment is Python 3.7, Django 2.2, Pyinstaller 3.4, Windows 7. Everything is under a virtual environment.

Have anyone run into that problem? Is there any workaround to it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I encountered this problem, can you tell me how to solve it

Comment: Please look at my answer below. The general idea is to copy all `.py` or `.pyc` files to `dist/apps` directory either manually or automatically (using .spec-file and its section "added_files"). They are not copied during .exe generation. Not only it's true for admin files but also for any other source files of the project.

Comment: Thanks  SO much for your reply, I see hope:)  This is my step: I used "pyi-makespec -D manage.py" to generate "manage.spec" file, added hiddenimports and datas in it, used "pyinstaller manage.spec" to generate dist. Run "manage.exe runserver" in "/dist/manage/". So,where I should copy files to? I see no "apps" folder in " /dist/manage/ ", I can't post picture to show my directory structure in the comment.  And in my original project, models folder contain "admin.py .etc.py" and a "__pycache__ folder " contain  .pyc. Do I need to copy entire models folder with the original directory structure?

Comment: Or could you please send me a demo dist packet, so I know how to copy it? my mail is 137190@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out. The source files (admin.py and models.py) or their compiled .pyc versions of each model must be presented in the "dist\~project name~\apps\~app name~\" at least when the .exe file is being started. After that these files might be deleted. Please tell me if there is another workaround.